# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Line 67 after moved to live

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

getting `TokenMismatchException` in `VerifyCsrfToken.php` Line 67 error after moved to live server from local.

Comment: Make sure all storage folders are included on the server. - app/framework (with cache, sessions, views)/logs -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Give storage folder on root 777 permission recursively. and clear cache folder.